# Haskell data of Explanation

Tags: haskell

I'm looking for a good Explanation for this ´Of` after data Card:

```
data Suit = Club | Diamond | Spade | Heart deriving (Eq, Show, Ord, Enum)
data Value = Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven | Eight | Nine | Ten | Bobe | Dame | King | Ass deriving (Ord, Eq, Show, Enum)

data Card = Value `Of` Suit
    deriving (Show)
```

I didn't make it to google a good Doc or explanation.

Comment: it's just a *inline* data-constructor - it's like `mod m n` vs ``m `mod` n`` - so you might be expecting `data Card = Of Value Suit` but this reads much better don't you think?

Comment: can you recommend a good source for further explanation?

Comment: *infix* is the keyword here. Backticks are just syntax for infix notation.

Comment: if it is helpful you can decide to mark one of the answers as "accepted"

Comment: thanks. did not know that !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In haskell any (non operator, non partially aplied) function, i.e. with  type signature `f :: a -> b -> c`, can be used infix - with the use of *backtick-syntax*, which you surround the function with backticks, e.g.

```
mod m n = m `mod` n
```

here the first argument of the function goes to the left hand side of the "operator" and the second one to the right.

For the reverse, if you have an operator `+` and you want to apply it in prefix notation you simply surround it with `(`,`)`

```
a + b = (+) a b
```

Coming back to your algebraic data type, writing it in the usual way

```
data Card = Of Value Suit deriving (...)
```

If you now load your file or paste your definitions into `ghci` you can ask the interactive compiler about the types of your expressions.

```
$ > ghci
GHCi, version 7.10.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> data Suit = Heart |... deriving Show
Prelude> data Value = One |... deriving Show
Prelude> data Card = Of Value Suit deriving Show
Prelude> :t Of
Of :: Value -> Suit -> Card
```

Which is exactly the type we need to use infix syntax - then we can use it in the following form:

```
Prelude> One `Of` Heart
Of One Heart
```

Note: if you want to have a function of more than two parameters you have to give it a name like

```
:t foldl
foldl :: Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
Prelude> -- an example of a function with 3 parameters
Prelude> 0 `foldl (+)` [1..10]

<interactive>:14:10: parse error on input ‘(’
Prelude> let plus = (+)
Prelude> 0 `foldl plus` [1..10]

<interactive>:16:10: parse error on input ‘plus’
```

does not work, but this will

```
Prelude> let sumStartingAt = foldl (+)
Prelude> 0 `sumStartingAt` [1..10]
55
```

Answer (score 2):

The value constructor is just a function. Check it in ghci.

```
Prelude> data T = F Int Int | Int `G` Int deriving Show
Prelude> :t F
Int -> Int -> T
Prelude> 1 `F` 2
F 1 2
Prelude> :t G
Int -> Int -> T
Prelude> G 1 2
G 1 2
```

As it is a function, you can use the infix form.

Maybe it is the infix declaring form is bothering you. It is just another way to express.

```
type P = (Int, Int)
(#*) :: P -> P -> Int
(a, b) #* (c, d) = a * d - b * c
```